# Push Notification in Asp.net for windows 8.x devices

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8, windows-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am working in ASP.net and want to send the push notification to windows phone and windows 8 devices using ASP.NET(C#). How can I achieve this.Can you provide the detail on the same. I have little bit Knowledge about Windows Azure,C#.net and Asp.net".

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Phone, there is [an article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221551.aspx). Similarly, there is an article [for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx)

Comment: How should be implemented in the asp.net web app